# How to iterate over keys in array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have an array, say:

```
products = [['product_1','description 1'],['product_2','description 2']]
```

And I want to check input against the keys, e.g.,:

```
product = raw_input('Enter product:  ')
if product not in products.keys():
    log.fatal('Invalid product: {}'.format(product))
    exit(1)
```

`keys()` doesn't work -- what should I be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lists dont have keys ... you just want the first element of each sublist

```
dict(products).keys() #ONLY if there is exactly 2 items per sublist
```

or

```
zip(*products)[0] #any number of items per sublist is ok
```

or

```
[k for k,val in products] # only if you have EXACTLY 2 items per sublist
```

or

```
[item[0] for item in products]  # any number of items in each sublist
```

Answer (score 2):

`keys` is not a method of a `list`. You must be thinking of a `dict`. Just do:

```
products = {k: v for k, v in [['product_1','description 1'],['product_2','description 2']]}
```

Comment: or just call `dict` on your list directly ... good answer all the same